# Remove newlines in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml

Is there a way to write a very long xml request in multiple lines instead of just one? When I write it in multiple lines, the string is not accepted because of the newlines inserted. How can I add newlines in my text editor with adding the newlines in the actual program? I am using sublime.

Comment: Show here example of multiple line text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ruby

```
str = "this is \n multi-line \n text \n\n"
puts str 
# this is
# multi-line
# text
```

Use [gsub!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) to modify the string

```
str.gsub!("\n","") 
puts str # this is  multi-line  text
```

#### Rails

Use [squish](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/3.2.6/String%3asquish) to remove all unnecessary white space

```
str = "this is \nmulti-line \n text \n\n"
puts str.squish # this is multi-line text
```